# Where is cloud-config.yml in coreOS?

Tags: coreos

I can't find where cloud-config.yml is in coreOS.

If anyone knows, please teach me cloud-config.yml location in coreOS.

If it does not exist, where should I make one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud-config is typically stored in your cloud providers metadata service, which is a network address that returns the config. For bare metal, it's normally stored on disk if the OS was installed, or held in RAM if the server was PXE-booted.

Here's a full list of locations: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config-locations.html

Comment: Thanks! Should I make one if not exists?

Comment: If you want to use the functionality, yes. On most platforms, it is hard to log in if you don't, since CoreOS doesn't set a default password and instead relies on SSH keys.